# How to broadcast gRPC streams inter pods

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-pod

We have gRPC stream to share data between two micro services, an API and a Worker (both created in Golang). The intention is to listener about the status of jobs being processed by Worker service pods. So, the communication is one-directional (Worker sends updates to Api). The figure below shows it.
[image]

Our problem is, how can I managed to know when Worker's pod scales up, in order to subscribe to new Worker pod (by stream)?

The figure below shows the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not possible for your use case, but have you thought about having a service in front of the worker, so instead of subscribing to both workers, you subscribe to one of the two?

If you *need* to subscribe to both workers, one thing you can do is to use the k8s API client and watch the pod resource with a selector that selects your worker pod (by name, or some other label), and subscribe to it if a new one pops up. That'll probably require you to setup a cluster role and a cluster role binding for the listener pods so they can watch pod resources. This scheme will also allow you to unsubscribe from workers when they die.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea: why not using a central configuration storage (like etcd, redis,..) to synchronize the workers with the gRPC-API, this kind of logic need to be managed by the application itself, in details:

1. when a new worker-pod starts, it register itself on the configuration service
2. when the application gRPC-API requires to establish a new connection, it looks on on the configuration service and the application chooses one: it is up to you to decide which kind of strategy you want to use there, round-robin, random, stickiness,...etc
3. when a worker-pod is then shutted-down, the entry of that destination is removed from the configuration service. To avoid ghost entries, it is probably better in place a custom monitoring tool or that gRPC-API takes the responsibility to check the validity of the destination before start a new connection

This should do the trick that you are looking for.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I am confused, your answer says "that is not possible" and here that "k8s already does it"?

Comment: what may not be possible is using services. Using k8s apis works just fine for this scenario once the cluster role is setup and it works just the way you described. Even better, you do not have to poll. You will get notifications when pods are created. Also #2 in you description is how k8s services work.

Comment: @BurakSerdar here I meant to solve the problem inside the application, as you say it would be possible to re-use some k8s native functionalities, however seems that gRPC-API and the worker are custom components, you need anyway to integrate the required new logic into them